# Select MAX Value in a group and it's identity key

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table in SQL Server:

```
Id    Type     Date  
--------------------------------------
1     80       2014-00-00 00:00:00.000
2     80       2013-00-00 00:00:00.000
3     81       2012-00-00 00:00:00.000
4     81       2011-00-00 00:00:00.000
5     81       2010-00-00 00:00:00.000
```

I want to get records with max date in else type like following, how to query?

```
Id    Type     Date  
--------------------------------------
1     80       2014-00-00 00:00:00.000
3     81       2012-00-00 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  ID,
        [Type],
        [Date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b3b9/1) with a demo of this.

And the results are:

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Id ║ Type ║          Date           ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║   80 ║ 2014-00-00 00:00:00.000 ║
║  3 ║   81 ║ 2012-00-00 00:00:00.000 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════════════════════╝
```